# Display data in RTF in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have data in my database that is in Rich Text Format. Is there a way to display this type of data in a Crystal Report so that its formatted properly?

BTW, I'm using Crystal Reports 11.5 Release 2

Comment: Did the below answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the field, then select Format Field -> Paragraph tab -> Text Interpretation -> RTF text.

Be aware that RTF doesn't always display like you expect it to.  It's a little like how different browsers display the same html/css in various different ways and all have a little quirky behavior... except in my experience...  RTF is way more quirky and frustrating.

Good luck.